# SuperClass field for junit4 testing on Android Studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, junit4

I am starting with testing and I am using Android Studio for test a dummy class. I am creating the test using Android Studio itself but it asks me for a superclass.
What should I type on that field?

[image]

Comment: Try continuing without selecting / writing anything :)

Comment: Yes I did but I guess it is not the best way :)